# Trying to deploy my react app to github, but having some errors when running it

Tags: github, git-bash

I am trying to deploy my react app to github, but when i'm running npm run deploy i'm getting the below error message

remote: Permission to aneagoie/robofriends.git denied to Moshe844.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/aneagoie/robofriends.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

can you please help me with getting this resolved?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "robofriends",
  "homepage": "https://Moshe844.github.io/robofriends",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "tachyons": "^4.12.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-error-overlay": "^6.0.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your GitHub account is `Moshe844`, based on the error message and `"homepage"`, but your remote is configured to point to `aneagoie`'s repository. You can't push to someone else's repo unless they explicitly invite you as a collaborator.

Comment: is there a way to get around it?  like moving the project to Moshe844?

Comment: Yes, read e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo

Comment: i followed the above link, everything was successfully, however when in did npm run deploy, i got the same error message
remote: Permission to aneagoie/robofriends.git denied to Moshe844.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/aneagoie/robofriends.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: see below it looks like the fork was successfully 
mekstein@FPS104 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/robofriends (master)
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/aneagoie/robofriends.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/aneagoie/robofriends.git (push)
upstream        https://github.com/Moshe844/robofriends.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/Moshe844/robofriends.git (push)

mekstein@FPS104 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/robofriends (master)

any ideas?

Comment: Read the output - you're still trying to deploy to the wrong repo. Maybe read the `gh-pages` docs to see if you can configure which remote is used, or switch around the labels to use the convention for which is yours and which is the fork.